# Django get url variables within get_context data?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Say I have a url likes this

```
    path(
        'foo/<int:foo_id>/edit/',
        views.FooView.as_view(),
        name='foo',
    ),
```

and a view likes this:

```
    def get(self, request, foo_id):
```

I find a common idiom is getting the URL variable `foo_id` into the context.

The only thing context has access to be default is `request`. I tried checking `request` and `request.GET` and could not see anything.

Is there a better way than:

- Manually adding url variables to the `context_data` after `get_context_data()`
- or passing it into `get_context_data` from a custom call from `get`? (ugly because class based views expect the same get_context_data signature)

Comment: One thing though is considering that you are passing an id to the view, I would expect you to deal with some object and pass that in the context (example `DetailView` etc.) considering that can't you simply access the id from the object? e.g. `object.id` or `object.pk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url parameters are stored in the `.kwargs` of the `view`. You thus can access and render these with:

```
{{ view.kwargs.foo_id }}
```

There is a reference with the name `view` that is passed which is the `View` object that is constructed when handling a request. We thus access the `.kwargs` attribute of that `View` object, and in the `kwargs`, we look for `kwargs['foo_id']`.

A peculiarity in Django is that a [**`TemplateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView) passes all it `kwargs` items as context data, if your view is thus a `TemplateView`, then you can render this with

```
<!-- only a TemplateView -->
{{ foo_id }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! That sounds perfect, unfortunately, for me with django 3.2 in the template `{{view.kwargs.foo_id}}`, `{{view.kwargs}}`, `{{view}}`, `{{kwargs}}` and are all blank. Just researching if they removed that feature. I do however see in the view `self.kwargs` is a dict containing `foo_id`, which does answer my question. Getting in the template would of been even better.

Comment: @run_the_race are you using the generic `View` class or some other class like `DetailView`, etc.? If you are using `View` then it doesn't inherit `ContextMixin` and hence the view is not passed in the context (It doesn't even use `get_context_data` unless you implement it that way).

Comment: @run_the_race: as @AbdulAzizBarkat says, this will work for a view that at least inherits from the [`ContextMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin) (which is nearly every view except a simple `View`). For that simple `View` there is no logic at all to render the template, so implementing a simple `View` is usually only done to implement boilerplate code[.

Comment: Yes I am using `generic.View`, that explains it, learn a lot from that, thanks guys!

Comment: @run_the_race: a simple way to fix this is inherit from the `ContextMixin` and `TemplateResponseMixin` as well, so `class MyViewClass(TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin, View):`, this should be sufficient to access the URL parameters if you work with `self.render_to_response(..)`

Comment: Wish I could upvote this answer again, thank you, I am refering to it again almost a year later!